# Plug an Android phone into a USB sound card using a 4-poles 3.5 mm cable

Tags: smartphones, sound-card

I thought that it can be helpful for other people that are doing testing on mobile devices these days, so I would like to know if one can plug an Android phone into a USB sound card using a 4-poles 3.5 mm cable (no splitter in between).

[image]

The USB sound card belongs to a [Razer BlackShark V2 Gaming Headset](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086PKMZ1Q). The idea is to use the computer as a microphone for the smartphone so that one can control what audio is transmitted during a call.

Comment: Yes. But I would be careful with the volume. The audio output from your phone is meant to drive headphones and is much more powerful than the tiny signal from a microphone. The DAC might not be expecting a signal that strong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't that simple.

You need the earphone output of each going into the microphone output of the other.

You need at a minimum a sort of "cross over" cable.

That won't be enough, though.

The signal level of the earphone outputs is too high for the microphone inputs.

You need to reduce the earphone level to what the microphone requires.

We had a [similar question recently.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/560694/how-to-connect-one-android-mobile-audio-output-to-the-microphone-of-another-andr)  The result is that you need a circuit like this:

[image]

You need one of those in each direction.

Whether you use splitters and other cables to connect a four pole Android phone and a three pole (or four pole) PC isn't all that important.  The fact of it is, though that you'll need some passive components to make it work properly.

---

You may or may not need the 2k resistor across the microphone on the PC side.  Some recognize the microphone plug mechanically, others electrically.

Comment: You even created an article that I can reference to respect copyrights: https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/androidtranscribe5. Thanks for resolving that too.